# Is there a way to get a click callback in plotly express bar chart?

Tags: plotly, bar-chart, plotly-python, plotly-express

I am using bar chart from plotly express in one of my desktop applications. I want to know if it is possible to create a callback on click event on any of the bars? I want to track which bar has been clicked (may be x data point of the bar should be enough in the callback)?

Sample code to generate the bar chart as below:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'month':['2022-02-01','2022-03-01','2022-04-01','2022-05-01'],'value':[10,15,20,5]})
barplot = px.bar(df, x="month", y="value")
```

I am not using a Dash (Plotly).

Comment: What do you want to do with the information? If you're going to use that information to, say, update the chart, then you could try using a `go.FigureWidget` [click event](https://plotly.com/python/click-events/) but if you want to do something more involved that involves saving or keeping track of the stored information, you'll probably have to use `plotly-dash` - a good starting point would be [here](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing)

Comment: @Derek Thank you for your comment. I want to drilldown the data by click event in a different chart. let say if you click on a bar for "2022-02-01" I want to break the value 10 by day and display the bar chart by day in a different chart. I believe Dash is only used for web development and not for a desktop application (mine is a desktop application). Please correct if I am wrong. I had already tried the first link you mentioned but with bar chart I am not able to detect which bar was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time dealing with click events, but I was able to get click events on bar graphs with the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/click-events/#update-points-using-a-click-callback) and answers from the [community](https://community.plotly.com/t/interactive-graph-click-event/19219). I am sorry I cannot give you a technical explanation.

```py
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from ipywidgets import Output, VBox
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'month':['2022-02-01','2022-03-01','2022-04-01','2022-05-01'],'value':[10,15,20,5]})

f = go.FigureWidget([go.Bar(x=df['month'], y=df['value'])])

barplot = f.data[0]
colors = ['#a3a7e4'] * 4
barplot.marker.color = colors
# scatter.marker.size = [10] * 100
f.layout.hovermode = 'closest'

# create our callback function
out = Output()
@out.capture(clear_output=True)
def update_point(trace, points, selector):
    c = list(barplot.marker.color)
    print(points.point_inds)
    for i in points.point_inds:
        c[i] = '#bae2be'
        with f.batch_update():
            barplot.marker.color = c

barplot.on_click(update_point)

VBox([f, out])
```

**Image when clicking on the second bar (1 in the lower left)**

[image]